# How to stream RTSP behind firewall to server

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, ip-camera, rtsp

I'm looking for a way to unicast the video stream of an IP camera to a VPS on the internet for recording and live viewing. Like on any network, the IP camera is behind a firewall, and also port forwarding is not an option here. Is there a way for me to convert the RTSP stream from the camera and unicast it to the server? I've looked around and most streaming protocols require the stream destination to make the connection to the stream source, but I need it to be the other way around. Is there any existing software or protocol that will do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ffmpeg` with RTMP output.

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen -i rtsp://ownaddress/live.sdp [encoding parameters] -f flv rtmp://yourvps.com/rtmp/key
```